# Show that a conditional probability distribution of a Pareto-distributed random variable is also Pareto.

Tags: statistics

I have a Pareto-distributed rv $T$, with PDF $f(t) = \dfrac{\alpha \theta^\alpha}{t^{\alpha +1}}$, $T>\theta$ and $\theta, \alpha>0$.

I am asked to show that the conditional probability distribution where $T> t_0$ is also a Pareto.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I notice that someone voted to close this question, and I wonder what anyone considering doing that thinks of the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the density function of the random variable $T$.  Then
\begin{align}
\Pr(s < T < t \mid T>t_0) & = \frac{ \Pr( s < T < t\ \&\  T>t_0) }{\Pr(T>t_0)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\Pr(s<T<t)}{\Pr(T>t_0)} \quad \text{if } s\ge t_0 \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\displaystyle\int_s^t f(x)\,dx}{\Pr(T>t_0)} = c\int_s^t f(x)\, dx \\
& (\text{The denominator is a “constant'' since it} \\
& \phantom{(}\text{does not depend on } x, \text{ which goes from } s \text{ to } {t.})
\end{align}
Thus the conditional density is $cf(x)$ for $x>t_0$, and $0$ for $x<t_0$. To find $c$, just use the fact that
$$
c\int_{t_0}^\infty f(x)\, dx = 1.
$$
Once you've done that, you need to observe that the density is the same as what you started with except that $(1)$ it's $0$ if $x<t_0$ and $(2)$ you have $t_0$ where earlier you had $\theta$.